# Relative Error in Compensated Summation

Tags: floating-accuracy, numerical-methods, floating-point-precision, numerical-analysis

I have implemented Kahan's Compensated Summation (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm) algorithm for randomly generated double precision data and need to calculate relative error.

As per various papers, in order to calculate relative error, we need exact summation. My question is how is exact summation calculated? Can we calculate exact summation using extended precision libraries like MPFR?

If exact summation cannot be calculated then how is relative error calculated?

Or relative error is calculated as (kSum-recSum)/kSum where kSum is sum calculated with Kahan's method and recSum is recursive summation of floating point numbers? But that does not seem right.